# How can I find pnputil in windows restore command line?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, drivers, cmd.exe

My Windows fails to start, I assume due to one of the drivers. In order to uninstall it I try to use pnputil.

For folders "X:\windows\system32" and  "X:\windows\syswow64" cmd says command is not recognized and etc. dir pnputil.* for windows directory gives noting.

How can I find pnputil or what other approach I can use to delete the driver, other than restore point which doesn't work for me.

I'm not able to load in safe mode, all I've got is this command promt.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an X: drive I assume you booted from a CD/DVD/USB of the install media or windows PE, in which case you can use [DISM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-driver-servicing-command-line-options-s14).

Note it could be a different drive letter.

```
dism /Image:c:\ /Remove-Driver /Driver:oem1234.inf
dism /Image:c:\ /Add-Driver /Driver:c:\drivers /Recurse
```